# Infinite loop for vue-router's beforeEach method

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, infinite-loop

I want to replace one of the `params` of `to` if `to`'s name is a specific one and I have no idea why this doesn't work.

```
export const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 };
  },
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'Details Page',
      path: 'details/:name/:id',
      component: () => import('@/views/Details.vue'),
      meta: {
        encode: true,
      },
    },
    // other routes... (none of them has encode = true)
  ]
});

function needsEncode(route) {
  return route.meta && route.meta.encode;
}

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name === 'Details Page' && needsEncode(to)) {
    const toEncoded = Object.assign({}, to, {
      meta: {
        encode: false,
      },
      params: {
        name: encodeURIComponent(to.params.name),
        id: to.params.id,
     },
    });
    return next(toEncoded);
  }
  return next();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't store state in the `meta` property. Instead you can check if the name is already encoded:

```js
function needsEncode(route) {
  return route.meta && route.meta.encode && ( // <-- changes start here
    decodeURIComponent(to.params.name) === to.params.name
  ) // <-- changes ends here
}
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name === 'Details Page' && needsEncode(to)) {
    const toEncoded = Object.assign({}, to, {
      // remove meta
      //meta: {
      //  encode: false,
      //},
      params: {
        name: encodeURIComponent(to.params.name),
        id: to.params.id,
     },
    });
    return next(toEncoded);
  }
  return next();
}
```

If `decodeURIComponent(to.params.name)` is equal to the name, then it's not encoded yet and you can proceed to encode it.

Comment: After a few tests, I marked this as the accepted answer but now I notice a problem. If `to.param.name` is a string which always remains the same whether it is decoded or encoded, it enters an infinite loop again. e.g. `'xyz' === decodeURIComponent('xyz') === encodeURIComponent('xyz')`.

Comment: I found kind of a silly solution now :) When encoding `to.param.name` I add `%20` at the end of it (like this `${encodeURIComponent(to.params.name)}%20`). This way when it's decoded it's always different